# Get elements of Series B not in A

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way to find the elemens in B that are not in A?

The index column of both sets is to be used for the comparison.  The other column is to be carried with the results.

Here is a sample, keeping in mind that series A and B can get huge:

```
print a
    c2
c1    
o80  a
o81  b

print b
    c2
c1    
o83  c
o81  b
```

Here is the desired result:

```
print c
    c2
c1    
o83  c
```

After each comparison, the results C will be appended to a running results series.

I can do the job, with combine_first, comparing the results, etc, but it doesn't look elegant and simple and won't scale well.

Any insights from those who are really experienced at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use logical indexing:

```
c1 = pandas.Series([1, 2], index=['A', 'B'], name='c1')
c2 = pandas.Series([3, 4, 5], index=['A', 'B', 'C'], name='c2')
c2[~c2.index.isin(c1.index)]
```

give me:

```
C    5
Name: c2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks pretty simple.